# What are best practices for scaling databases/disk storage on google cloud infrastructure?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

We're in the process of migrating our application to Google Cloud after receiving enough credits from Google's startup program to give us free cloud for a year.

Our web application is fairly light on the backend as it for the most part just operates as a REST API. It's built using Django and PostgreSQL.

Our initial plan was to just use **Google App Engine**, but that would've required us to basically redesign our database and backend by migrating to NoSQL, which would've most likely been quite an ordeal due to our data structure relying quite heavily on joins and project like http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine seem to have quite sever limitations and to make thing more complicated, there are a bunch of tools we've come to use that also require shell access.

We were then hoping to be able to use **Compute Engine** (GCE) but now it would seem that in order to scale our database, we'd have to implement and maintain a separate sharded cluster ourselves. **Would there be an easier way to add some redundancy and load balancing to our database structure?**

Our current best bet would seem to be to use GCE for the actual application and then migrate to use **Google Cloud SQL** alongside. The problem with that is that it only supports MySQL and we'd prefer to use Postgres because of the excellent NoSQL support it has that we were planning to use for some of our upcoming features.

Google does have lots of excellent documentation regarding the practicalities but very little in terms of architectural guidance and best practices on their Cloud platform. **What's your take on our situation? What kind of best practices would there be out there?**

Comment: be aware that the starter packs for cloud platform are usually very generous but normally are limited to about 3 months in validity.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @koma, our is fortunately valid for 12 months :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to have the best of both worlds IaaS and PaaS by going for AppEngine in combination with managed VMs. AppEngine will then spin up VM instances on Compute Engine that are not bound to the restrictions that ordinary GAE instances must obey to.
A managed VM will allow you to connect to your existing Postgress database without any code modifications.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/